# Ajax request not updating the bean

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following snippet (inside `h:body->h:form`, `h:head` has been used):

```
<p:dataTable id="items" value="#{faNav.faRequest.items}" var="_item" emptyMessage="#{dict['web.faRequest.noItems']}">
    <p:column>
        <h:inputText id="newItemName" value="#{_item.name}" rendered="#{_item.name eq null}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
-->         <p:spinner id="newItemQuantity" value="#{_item.quantity}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton value="Añadir" update="items" actionListener="#{faNav.addItem}" rendered="#{_item.name eq null}"/> 
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And the function in the bean:

```
public void addItem(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("Añadiendo");
    this.faRequest.getItems().add(new RequestItem());       
}
```

Now, with the debugger I check the values inside the function. There, the `name` property has been updated with the value from the form, but the `quantity` integer has not. The property is name, because if I set a default non-zero value for quantity, the form shows it correctly.

I am using Primefaces 3.4.2 on JBoss 7.1

What I am missing? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Switching from `<p:spinner>` to `<h:inputText>` does not help at all.

Comment: does it work when you try `update="@form"` ?

Comment: @fischermatte: OP checked the model values inside the action listener method, so the ajax render is irrelevant. As to possible `update="items"` fail on a datatable, this was fixed in PF 3.3 and OP is using 3.4.2.

Comment: @fischermatte I finally found it, if you want to check the answer. Thanks for your efforts anyway.

Comment: You didn't have `rendered` on the quantity input in the initial question, that's why no one was able to see the cause. As to the cause, it's indeed fully expected behaviour. If the input is evaluated as not rendered during apply request values phase, then it won't be processed.

Comment: @BalusC you are right, I don't remember if it was pasted from a test I didn't check properly of if I deleted the attribute because I "was sure" that it was not related. Either way, what puzzles me is the fact that, by setting the two values **at the same time**, they were affecting each other; I was expecting that the steps would be 1-3-2-4.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, there was no issue with primefaces but with the `rendered` attribute:

The smaller SSCCE I got was

index3.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head/>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText id="newItemName" value="#{faNav.item.name}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText id="newItemQuantity" value="#{faNav.item.quantity}" rendered="#{faNav.item.name eq null}"/>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:commandButton value="Añadir" actionListener="#{faNav.setItem}" rendered="#{!faNav.item.containsData}"/> 
    </h:column>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

fixedAssetNav.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="faNav")
@ViewScoped
public class FixedAssetNav implements Serializable {

RequestItem item = new RequestItem();

public RequestItem getItem() {
    return this.item;
}

public void setItem(RequestItem item) {
    this.item = item;
}

public void setItem(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    this.item.setContainsData(true);
    System.out.println("Setting " + this.item.getName() + " " + this.item.getQuantity());
}
}
```

`RequestItem` is just a plain bean with two String attributes (`name` and `quantity`) and a boolean one (`containsData`).

I found out that by changing the order of the fields in the .xhtml (moving `newItemQuantity` before `newItemName`) did solve the problem. Also, removing the `rendered` attribute of `newItemQuantity` or changing the expression to `true` did also work).

My guess is that, when applying values, the procedure was:

1) Check if `newItemName` was rendered.
2) If it was the attribute `name` is updated.
3) Check if `newItemQuantity` was rendered
4) If it was the attribute `quantity` is updated.

But the step 3 checked the expression (`faNav.item.name eq null`) **after** updating the model, so it suddenly was false and step 4 was skipped.

A more convenient way of solving this is checking the phase for the attribute:

```
        <h:inputText id="newItemQuantity" value="#{faNav.item.quantity}" rendered="#{(faNav.item.name eq null) || (facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal ne 6)}"/>
```